# Routing in greasemonkey userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I currently have kind of a toolbox for a website, separated in various files that do different things to different parts of the page.

For example: one script runs on `www.idk.com`, another runs on `www.idk.com/article/*`, so on so forth.

What I want is a way to dispatch the execution of each script to bundle everything in one package. This package would run on all `www.idk.com` and decide which scripts to execute based on the URL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232750/multiple-greasemonkey-metablocks/3243697#3243697 for one possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use regex-matching on the value of `location.href`?

Comment: So you are saying: move each individual script to a function and then call the appropiate function. Didnt thought about it. I guess i was expecting some kind of dependency, but this looks good to me. Ill try and report back.