# Best way to differentiate between different pages inside greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

For example I want to add some features to google.com home page and google.com search results page, and I want to do it in one greasemonkey script, I do:

```
@include http://google.com*
```

Then I check, if it's homepage, I add the third button under search box for example, if it's the results page I change font or something like that.

What would be the best way to differentiate between these pages? I currently do

```
if (document.URL==="homepage") {
    add button
} else if (document.URL==="searchpage") {
    change font
}
```

would switch be better? is there a better solution?

Comment: One neat technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232750/multiple-greasemonkey-metablocks/3243697#3243697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` is faster and more efficient than a series `if/else if`

I often use is for that purpose.

```
// caching path is faster (although the difference is only milliseconds)
var path = location.pathname;

switch (true) {

  /* ----- Home page ----- */
  case path.indexOf('/path1') !== -1:
    addButton();
    break;

  /* ----- Search page ----- */
  case path.indexOf('/path2') !== -1:
    changeFont();
    break;
}
```

**Update:**
Using ES6 [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
var path = location.pathname;

switch (true) {

  /* ----- Home page ----- */
  case path.includes('/path1'):
    addButton();
    break;

  /* ----- Search page ----- */
  case path.includes('/path2'):
    changeFont();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use switch.